# How can we clean up the mess?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wrote a [question on UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/design-pattern-or-best-practices-for-top-notification-bars) about Top NOTIFICATION bars. This was extensively re-written by [Glen Lipka](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/342/glen-lipka). I thought this was great until I realized he was talking about Top Navigation bars.

I guess we should now create two new question and delete the original (as it was not well written). One question should have Glen as owner.

How do we go about doing that, or are there some other ways to sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You could make the question community wiki so neither of you get rep, but the question can still be answered.
- You can delete the question and ask a new one, and Glen could copy/paste his text into a new question.
- You can roll back the edits and let Glen copy/paste his text from the version history.

Comment: The ten minute wait was really rewarding :)

Answer (score -1):

I wasnt talking about top NAV bars at all.  I am talking about the design pattern for top bars for ANY purpose.  I included both nav and notification.  It can also be used for search and other purposes.  I didnt say anything limiting it to navigation.

Comment: This will teach me to ever edit anyone's question.

Comment: The point is that you changed the subject of the question to such an extent that GUI Junkie feels s/he no longer owns it. You shouldn't stop editing questions, just take away from this particular edit that you "over-edited" a little bit.

Comment: You win some, you lose some.  In this case, I think its still a misunderstanding.  I expanded, not switched the topic.